# $_GET data can't be read in isset $_POST function

Tags: php, ajax

I am creating a form for users to change their passwords and to do this I get their username from the url and $_GET the data.

For example:

> Website.com/passwordreset.php?username=moonman&key=d77e39f7f6ea2410bfbb59e7f96320ea81eed443fa31d9d327c37635ce28c9a2

```
// PHP //

$key = $_GET['key'];
$username = $_GET['username'];

if(isset($_POST["password"])){
        echo $key;
        echo $username;
        echo $_GET['key'];
        echo $_GET['username'];
        echo "Test";
}

//Ajax//

function passwordchange(){
    var password1 = _("password1").value;
    var ajax = ajaxObj("POST", "passwordreset.php");
    ajax.onreadystatechange = function(){
    ajax.send("password="+password1);
    }
```

However the previous data seems to be unreadable when users try to send their new data through AJAX.
The output will be "Test" and nothing else.

Keep in mind that AJAX data can be sent perfectly and I tried working through with this by using sessions but failed.

Comment: Your question does not contain enough information to be answer-able.  What does the form look like, _exactly_, that allegedly posts this data? What does the AJAX call look like that you are referencing?

Comment: When doing your AJAX call, be sure that you pass the values **in the URL** and not through POgetST data. So if you want to send `password` as POST and `username` as get, you should send `{'password':'blablabla'}` as your POST data to the URL `website.com/yourScript.php?username=my_username`

Comment: @AlejandroIván Iván That helps a lot, but can you tell me how to send both GET and POST data with the context of my code?

Comment: @DevonReemor I could be of more help if you actually post the code you're using for doing your AJAX call. It's not a backend (PHP) issue, but rather an AJAX/Javascript one. EDIT: Nevermind, I just saw it.

Comment: `var ajax = ajaxObj("POST", "passwordreset.php?username=my_username");` here you'll need to add the username, this is data passed through GET (it's part of the address). Later in `ajax.send("password="+password1);` you're passing POST data.

Comment: @AlejandroIván 1000 thanks, wish you used the "answer question" button so I could give you some sort of reward for helping.

Comment: @DevonReemor don't worry, could you please answer your question by yourself, that way I can correct you if something's wrong and you can accept it.

Answer (score 0):

```
var ajax = ajaxObj("POST", "<?= $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ?>");
```

Problem was that i didn't take in the url which had the $_GET data.
Thank you to Alejandro Iván for helping me solve this problem.